# "The OAuth client was not found." from admin.directory API

Tags: google-oauth

When trying to obtain an access token through the admin.directory API, I get a 401 error: "The OAuth client was not found."  As best I can tell the url is properly formed, but I honestly have no idea if either of my client_id's qualify me for this API, or for OAuth2, since this is my first foray into same.  Is there a way to verify that a specific client_id is valid for a specific API?

Answer (score 0):

Your OAuth client ID is created in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).  Create a new client for a project (in the sidebar under "APIs & auth", select Credentials), and copy the client ID into your request. If you already have a client ID, perhaps you copied it incorrectly.

For an interactive demo, try the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). You can configure it to use your own OAuth client ID and redirect URIs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the OAuth Playground.  I'm still getting some errors, but debugging them this way is much clearer.